# Writing order string into text file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

This is only write "test 2" in the text file.
How to write the first line will be "test 1", and the second line will be "test 2" in the text file.

```
if(s1.equals("test 1")&&s2.equals("test 2")){
                WriteNameOrderInFile.nameOfFirstOrderForImage(s1);
                WriteNameOrderInFile.nameOfSecondOrderForImage(s2);
```

**WriteNameOrderInFile class:**

```
public class WriteNameOrderInFile(){

  public static void nameOfFirstOrder(String s) throws IOException {  
    String nameFileDoctor="C:/append info.txt";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nameFileDoctor);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    bw.write(s);
    bw.newLine();  
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();


}

  public static void nameOfSecondOrder(String s) throws IOException {  
    File file= new File("C:/append info.txt");

        FileOutputStream fos2= new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos2));
        bw.write(s);
        bw.newLine();  
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Any exceptions you've got? I've tried your code and it works for me (after calling both functions in a new main class). Probably you have to call the right functions `nameOfFirstOrder` and `nameOfSecondOrder`? Please provide a complete working code example.

Comment: I am really sorry, you are right, i called the wrong method. My mind is crazy. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the solution is only to call the correct methods, here are some improvements for your code:

```
public class WriteNameOrderInFile {
    public static void writeToFile(String text, boolean append) {
        File file = new File("C:/append info.txt");

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, append))) {
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do some exception handling
            System.err.println("Can't write to file!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // just a sample call with the code you provided
        String s1 = "test 1";
        String s2 = "test 2";

        if (s1.equals("test 1") && s2.equals("test 2")) {
            writeToFile(s1, false);   // boolean is false, so write (replace) text
            writeToFile(s2, true);    // append is true, so append text
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanations to the improvements of the code:

- Your two methods are only different on **writing** text to a file and **appending** text to a file. So consider using one method `writeToFile` and give it an **append**-boolean
- Instead of `OutputStreamWriter` and `FileOutputStream` consider using `FileWriter`
- If you're using Java with version >= 7, use try-with-resource statement. You can easily get rid of trying to close streams in a good manner.
- `BufferedWriter.flush()` is also not needed, since it will be done while closing the file (what is done by the try-with-resource statement)

Comment: Thank you for the improvment